# Error with Canon imageclass D480 driver in Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

After installing `libglade2` I was able to get the cannon drivers to install per the instructions:

```
dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_2.70-1_amd64.deb  
dpkg -i cndrvcups-ufr2-us_2.70-1_amd64.deb

/usr/sbin/lpadmin -p Lisas_Printer -m CNCUPSD490ZS.ppd -v lpd://192.168.1.150/Lisas_Printer -E
```

Then when I print a test page from the printer properties window under Ubuntu, I see the following status:

```
Idle - src = libcanon_pdlwrapper.c, line = 514, err = 0¥nDEBUG: PID 2262 (pdftops) exited with no errors.
```

I have tried removing and reinstalling, updating the system files, and am not sure how to dig into CUPS to debug further.  I am sure others must be encountering the same problem if you have a canon printer.

Thanks in advance for any insights you can share.

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 14.04 - x64

Install the following files in addition to Canon UFR drivers

`sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

Thanks to pdc on ubuntuforums.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265278

Comment: You saved my ass man

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the missing 32bit libraries are what cause this problem.  I had to run the following command twice as it stopped at one point.  Then it seems to work.

sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 ia32-libs lib32z1

This solution was found in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427330&page=10

I hope this helps someone else who struggling with the imageclass drivers on 12.04 x64.

Comment: In addition, I needed libjpeg62:i386 to get an iR C3380 connection to work.

Answer (score 2):

The same problem for Canon 4800 series (Canon i-Sensys 4890dw) and ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

1. download "UFRII/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux v2.80" from canon website.
2. try to install 32-bit deb files: "cndrvcups-common_2.80-1_i386.deb" and "cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.80-1_i386.deb"
3. Ubuntu package manager try to install them, and download some dependencies, but finally quit installation process without installing them.
4. try to install 64-bit deb files: "cndrvcups-common_2.80-1_amd64.deb"
5. ubuntu warn about repairing package.
6. click "repair" button.
7. try to install "cndrvcups-ufr2-uk_2.80-1_amd64.deb"
8. now add printer.

I hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Confirmed also on Linux Mint 19 (x86)** with the Canon driver version 3.60: unfortunately the driver is linked against the i386 version of libxml2. A quick ldd on the  /usr/lib/libcanonufr2.so just tell that libxml2.so.2 is not found (even if the x64 lib is present)
Installing the i386 version of the libxml2 fixes the problem.